# Buddypress send admin notification email when new subscriber registers

Tags: admin, buddypress, email, activation

I am running a Buddypress site, but I am not getting emails when a new subscriber registers. I have used a code in my functions.php that removes the activation email the user would receive (I want them auto activated and I am using a mailchimp auto responder to contact them upon registering instead).

I don't see where this code would disable the email that I should receive when they register, but I am a very novice wordpress user. Can anyone see something that I can change to allow me (the admin) to be notified when a user registers, but not send an activation email to the user?

```
function disable_validation( $user_id ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE $wpdb->users SET user_status = 0 WHERE ID=%d", $user_id ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_core_signup_user', 'disable_validation' );
function fix_signup_form_validation_text() {
  return false;
}
add_filter( 'bp_registration_needs_activation', 'fix_signup_form_validation_text' );

function disable_activation_email() {
return false;
}

add_filter( 'bp_core_signup_send_activation_key', 'disable_activation_email' );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't seem like anyone has any suggestions about this code. Can anyone point me in the right direction towards finding a solution that will email me (admin) anytime someone new registers to the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to your Network Admin dashboard, click on **Network Settings** under the Settings tab, and mark the check box:

> **Registration notification** - Send the network admin an email notification every time someone registers a site or user account.

Now whenever a new user registers, you will receive an email.